# windows 7 icons missing

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

After getting rid of 'black' icons on the desktop, all icons disappeared, only the texts remain. I can still start programs clicking on the texts. Icons disappeared also inside windows explorer, such as representing picture files as .jpg. General appearance of the windows has changed too such as were possible in windows XP. Have tried all suggested remedies found on the internet but without success. Seems like 'killing' the 'black' icons have killed a necessary process somewhere in the OS, but which?? Would hate to have to reinstall the whole system, as I have more then ons OS on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the icon cache to solve this. There is a batch file to download in the support article below

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

Comment: Already tried that and much more. Prolem seems to lie deeper. Suspect it has to do with the removal of the 'black' icons on the desktop

Comment: It is Windows 7.  Try System File Checker (SFC /SCANNOW from an admin command prompt).  Failing that, you may need to try a Windows 7 Repair Install.